# How to help users get a better browsing experience?

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-6

As I found out today, it looks like [YouTube is going to stop supporting IE6](http://www.techcrunch.com/2009/07/14/youtube-will-be-next-to-kiss-ie6-support-goodbye/) pretty soon.

This begs the question, should we, as applications builders, be the ones that are helping our users to get a better Internet experience?

Should we, like Google, provide messages to users with outdated browsers?

Should we be explaining to them what the advantages are to upgrading?

I understand we cannot force them to do anything and it would be tough to decide what makes something out of date. However, it seems that this would be a two-fold win. We get to develop better applications for newer browsers and we don't have to spend so much time making new and exciting things work in older crappy browsers.

Are there any other big name sites already doing this?

Comment: (-1) There have been a slew of questions relating to whether or not we should continue to support IE 6.

Comment: My question is not about IE6 in particular but more in general.

Answer (score 5):

I'm in favor of messages saying "you have IE, please update to something decent"... but if you're making websites for a company, it's sure that no one will let you do this, unless you're working at Google or Mozilla.

In the meantime, graceful degradation is my solution. I code for the latest browsers and I hack to get IE6 to work.

Comment: I hack to make IE6 usable, and don't bother trying to make more advanced features work in it.

Comment: Sometime it's not enought and the client asks for exact compliancy... but I agree your method is the best (it's also gmail's, for instance)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question of should we be the ones pointing our users in the right direction. If so, how and why?

Comment: I'm saying that we should but most of the time we can't. And for the why, we should because it'd improve the web!

Answer (score 3):

Often times the user works at a company that does not allow them to install software so bothering them about upgrading from IE 6 is pointless and needlessly aggravating them. Everyone knows that IE 6 is really not a great browser for developers (or many would argue users too) but a lot of people still use it. If your target audience doesn't really use it then maybe you can get away with bugging them about upgrading. But the question is do you really not want their money or their time on your site? You're risking that by asking them to upgrade. If you're making a product that you sell it doesn't really make a lot of sense to make them feel unwelcome on your site.

Comment: I think it's important to tell the users their browser is hindering their experience, but graceful degridation is still required.

Comment: If you are working for a company that has the ability to push whatever browser they want to their users, then don't you think it would be worth the fight to talk to IT (or whoever does the pushing) and at the very least update IE and preferably go with something like Firefox or even Chrome. There are a lot of business reasons to do so: developers time is saved by not having to hack for IE 6, better apps can be made, users will have less problems using the web in general.

Comment: It's often not me who is working at the company but rather my customers who have no choice about it. Yeah I can ask a big company to make some change for a small vendor like me but then again I'd rather just make it work and collect their money without hassling anyone.

Answer (score 2):

As developers and good citizens of the web, I feel it is our responsibility to courtiously educate others about the virtues of modern browsers.

IE6, and many other outdated browsers contain security holes that lead to computers infested with malware and increase the overall evil and spam on the web. Users trust developers not to hurt them, and it is our duty help our users get the best and safest experiences out of our products. Pointing out the security and functional virtues of modern browsers to our users only helps these aims.

Comment: I agree. Now the next question would be how do we tell them and what do we tell them?

Answer (score 1):

There was a **[great blog post](http://blog.digg.com/?p=878)** about this on Digg.com where they asked IE6 users a quick survey about why they were using IE6.

In short they asked them what they use at work **AND** at home, and why they used IE6.

The trouble is that a lot of them are at work, and (a) have no choice, or (b) have been told they can't upgrade, or (c) don't know why they should upgrade, or (d) they actually like IE6.

In almost all cases, there is very little you can do to help them upgrade... without frustrating them in the case of those that want to upgrade, but can't.

Linked pic (hope Digg doesn't mind)
[image]

Comment: I still believe that we are in a position to change this. Obviously there is someone who is making the decision to stick with IE 6. If the message/reasoning applies to their bosses and explains why they should push an update to all of their users then I think it could be important or helpful.

Comment: Agreed. Once more and more sites declare they have (or are going to) ditch IE6 support, it will go away as IT Admins are pressured to upgrade their ~8 year old browser software to something decent.  I too am guilty of supporting IE6 for *paying* customers, however for any new projects IE6 is off the table with warning up front that IE6 is not supported... with options and links to upgrade... including a link to a USB stick capable Portable Firefox for those that are only partially locked down.

Answer (score 0):

Which applications?  If your apps are for use by companies, or people working at companies, then you need to support IE 6 so it's usable.  Unfortunately, many companies seem to have intranet apps that require IE 6, and so aren't going to upgrade any time soon.  Moreover, a large number of people working for companies are unable to install a better browser, lacking admin rights.

If the target audience is people at home computers, then you can try to nudge people off IE 6.  Provide some links (i.e., to Firefox, Opera, Chrome, later versions of IE 6, whatever), making one link more obvious, so people who don't know the first thing about different browsers will have a default choice.  Bear in mind that there are a lot of people (including me) who are very unlikely to change browsers just to use your site.